model gpt-4o is not working on my chatbot
I tried using the new model 4o GPT on my chatbot but it doesn't work says it doesn't exist or I have don't have access to it , I don't think its the API key problem
entered the model name in app  file but it didn't work , expected the model to work

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
